# Pig job stuck on 0% Complete

Tags: apache-pig

I'm having a vary frustrating experience on pig right now.

a simple:

xyz = LOAD 'location of xyz';
Dump xyz;

where as file xyz contains a simple text line like "I am Jack"

This simple tack gets stuck on 0% for ages, before the job eventually fails. I am using CDH5 hadoop-common-2.3.0-cdh5.1.0, so its not a memory issue.

There are a lot of people experiencing this problem, but I am yet to see a definitive answer.

QUESTION: How do i fix this problem

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: I ran into this to (also on CDH5), restarting YARN solved it. Possibly related https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-300

Comment: If you want people to help you figure out what is wrong, it helps a lot if you give more information about what is actually happening. What exact error message do you get, and what does the log look like?  Also, are you able to run other queries (like hive), and if you are using tez, does disabling help?